# For a fixed $f \in L^1(\Omega)$, find a coercive function $h$ such that $h(f) \in L^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces, coercive

I am looking for a proof of the following statement :

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a probability space and $f \in L^1(\Omega)$.

Show that there exists a **coercive function** $h$ ($h$ is positive, non-decreasing, with $\underset{t \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} \frac{h(t)}{t} = + \infty$) such that $h(f) \in L^1(\Omega)$.

If i am looking at a simple space like the space of real sequences equipped with the counting measure, it means that if a sequence of positive numbers $a_n$ verifies $$\sum_n a_n< +\infty$$
I can find $h$ coercive such that

$$\sum_n h(a_n)< +\infty$$

which i guess look quite possible by choosing $h$ such that $h(a_n)=\lambda_n a_n$ with $\lambda _n>0$ and $\lambda_n \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} + \infty$, but again I'm unsure how to detail that.

Any advices are welcomed.

Comment: The question in the title is totally different from the question in the body! In the title $h$ is required to be independent of $f$ (which is impossible), while in the second version $h$ may depend on $f$. Which version do you mean? You should edit the question...

Comment: Sorry you're totally right. The title is corrected now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: So it's not because I don't appreciate upvotes, but the solution below is wrong, I realized. Indeed, really it "proves" that any function in $L^p$ will also be in $L^{p+\delta}$ for suitably small ($f$-dependent) $\delta$. This is wrong, though.

Indeed, the mistake made is that I ended up applying monotone convergence to a *decreasing* net of functions and that does not fly. Take for instance the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx}$ on $[0,1]$. None of them are in $L^1$, but their limit sure is.

However, I did manage to find a proof.

Note that we may, without loss of generality, assume that $f$ is strictly positive. For general $f$ you can simply define $h$ that works for $f^+$ and set $\tilde{h}(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$.

Thus,
$$
\int_{\Omega} h(f)\textrm{d}\mu=\int_{\Omega} \frac{h(f)}{f} f\textrm{d}\mu=\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{h(x)}{x}\textrm{d}\nu, 
$$
where $\nu$ is the finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ given by the push-forward of the measure $f\textrm{d}\mu$ under $f$. Thus, writing $g(x)=\frac{h(x)}{x}$, we've rephrased the problem as: Given a finite measure $\nu$ on $(0,\infty)$, find a positive $g\in L^1(\nu)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=\infty$ and such that $g(x)x$ is non-decreasing. We can, without loss of generality, assume that $\nu$ is a probability measure and that $\nu$ has unbounded support (the bounded support case is trivial).

Define $b_0=0$ and recursively, define $b_{k+1}=\sup\{x\in (b_k,\infty)| \nu((b_k,x))\leq 2^{-(k+1)}\}$. Next, define $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k1_{(b_{k-1},b_k)}$ and note that

$$
\int_{(0,\infty)} g(x)\textrm{d}x= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \mu((b_{k-1},b_k))\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k 2^{-k}<\infty
$$
Furthermore, since $g$ is non-decreasing, $xg(x)$ will also be non-decreasing. Since $\nu$ has unbounded support, we have that $g$ is increasing and all in all, we get that $h(x)=xg(x)$ is a coercive function such that $\int_{\Omega} h(f)\textrm{d}\mu<\infty$.

Wrong solution:

Well, thinking of sequences does not exploit the strongest assumption that you've been given: That you're working on a probability space.

Define $h_{\alpha}(t)=(\max\{t,1\})^{\alpha},$ which is clearly coercive for any $\alpha>1$.

Note that, $\alpha\mapsto h_{\alpha}(t)$ is non-decreasing for every $t$. Applying monotone convergence, we get

$$
\int_{\Omega} \max\{f,1\} \textrm{d}\mu=\int_{\Omega} \lim_{\alpha\to 1} h_{\alpha}(f)\textrm{d}\mu=\lim_{\alpha\to 1} \int_{\Omega} h_{\alpha}(f)\textrm{d}\mu,
$$
Now, $\int_{\Omega} \max\{f,1\}\textrm{d}\mu\leq \int_{\Omega} |f|\textrm{d}\mu+\mu(\Omega)<\infty,$ so we must have that $\int_{\Omega} h_{\alpha}(f)\textrm{d}\mu<\infty$ for $\alpha$ sufficiently small.

This gives you the desired.

Comment: One may note that we're really using that $h_{\alpha}^{1/\alpha}\geq 1$ to get monotonicity and consequently, we also really need bounded functions to be integrable.

Comment: Now, given the correction, it seems to me like we're only really using that $f\in L^1$ and hence that $f\textrm{d}\mu$ is a finite (possibly signed) measure. Indeed, the mass of $\mu$ does not seem ot play a role.

Comment: Hello @WoolierThanThou, I've just seen that you changed your answer and i'm quite convinced by the new one. For the case when $\nu$ is with a bounded support, I guess one could take $g(x)=x$ which should work right ?

Comment: @Velobos For the case where $\nu$ has bounded support, *any* continuous, increasing function going to infinity would lie in $L^1(\nu)$ but sure, the identity works.